# New entry on a custom post type doesn't show up on the front end

Tags: wordpress

The former developer used this code, I can't seem to find the problem, everytime that we a new entry on the custom post type, it doesn't show it on front end.

You can check it here: https://www.pninjurylaw.com/case-results/
This should be shown as a new entry: https://www.pninjurylaw.com/caseresults/1-95-million-settlement-for-a-29-year-old-rear-ended-by-a-will-county-sheriff/ (disregard the full content not shown here)

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    //get children of page 241 and display with custom fields

    $args=array(                      
        'post_type' => 'caseresults',
        'posts_per_page'   => 9999,
        'meta_key'     => 'case_award',
        'orderby'      => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'            => 'DESC'
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>


    <div class="entry-content">


    <div class="entry-content clear"><div class="verdict-onethird"><?php the_field('case_verdict'); ?>:

        <span class="money"><?php the_field('amount'); ?></span>

        <?php // the_field('case_completion');?></div>
        <div class="verdict-twothird"><div class="singlepostcasedata">  

            <span class="header-verdict"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></span>

            <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'practicetype', '<span class="singlecatmeta">', '', '</span>' ); ?>
        </div><!-- end singlepostcasedata -->
        <?php the_field('case_summary'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>

    </div>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

       <?php endwhile; } ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().?>
```

Comment: are you sure that `case_award` is filled in the new post when testing?

Comment: because it sorts it by the `case_award` meta, and if that doesn't exist, it is skipped

Comment: I second what @Stender says. The posts will not be returned from the query if `case_award` meta key is not set. Try removing that from your query args and see if they are returned.

Comment: It actually worked, now my problem is the title of the new entry didn't come out

Comment: Fixed, changed the_excerpt() with the_title()